# How to fix powershell expression which causes error later in the code

Tags: powershell

I am trying to follow [this example](http://winsysadm.net/send-mail-with-inline-embedded-images-with-powershell/) in order to attach images to an email with powershell. Here is the part of the code that behaves strange:

```
if ($DirectoryInfo) {
    foreach ($element in $DirectoryInfo) {
        $failedTest = $element| Select-Object -Expand name          
        $failedTests += $failedTest
        $failedTestLog = "$PathLog\$failedTest.log"
        $logContent = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($failedTestLog)

        $imageDir = "$PathLog\$element\Firefox\*"
        $imageSearch = Get-ChildItem -Path $imageDir -Include *.png -Recurse -Force 
        $imageFullname = $imageSearch | select FullName | Select-Object -Expand Fullname
        $imageFilename = $imageSearch | Select-Object -Expand name
        $imageFilename
        $imageFullname

        # *** THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES THE ERROR ***
        $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList $imageFullname.ToString()    # *** CAUSING ERROR ***
        #$attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True
        #$attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
        #$attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/jpg"
        #$attachment.ContentId = '$imageFilename'
        #$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)

        $outputLog += "     

********************************************
$failedTest
********************************************
$logContent    
"
    }

} else {
  $outputLog = '** No failed tests **'
}



# Create the Overview report
$outputSummary = ""
foreach ($element in $scenarioInfo) {
    if (CheckTest $failedTests $element) {
        $outputSummary += "
$element : FAILED"                    # *** ERROR LINE ***
    } Else {
        $outputSummary += "
$element : Passed"
    }
}
```

If I comment out the line which defines the attachment, the code works fine. If I use the code as it is, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
At D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\LoadRunner\LRmain.ps1:112 char:11
+ $element : <<<<  FAILED"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (::String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

which refers to the line at the bottom of the script where it says "ERROR LINE". What the heck is going on? The behavior look completely illogical to me! I don't understand how a statement, which has no effect at all, can cause an error elsewhere!  What is the problem and how to fix it...?

Also it does not matter if I use `$imageFullname` or `$imageFullname.ToString()` in the offending line.

Comment: What is the output of  `$element` ? Are you sure there's a space between $element and the semicolon ?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Also, the problem is caused by the `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` line. If I comment out this line, the code 'works' and does not produce an error. I also cannot find any documentation on using an `ArgumentList` with that `Attachment` object...

Comment: Your code sample seems to have problems unrelated to the question.  The quote on the "ERROR LINE" spans multiple lines which is not allowed in PowerShell without using Here strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `"$element : FAILED"` by

```
"$element` : FAILED"
```

The reverse quote will escape the semicolon; which has a specific meaning in PowerShell. (It allows to output subproperty : `$env:username` for example)

Comment: But how can that problem be caused by using the `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` in the loop before that line of code?

Comment: Another syntax to avoid this would be 

    `"${element} : FAILED"`

Answer (score 0):

Define the `$outputSummary` as Array:

```
$outputSummary = @()
```

instead of

```
$outputSummary = ""
```

Comment: Does not change anything, I get the exact same error.